# Импорт в R c помощью scan

Tags: r

Пытаюсь импортировать данные в R из txt  помощью такой конструкции
`res <- scan("file.txt", what=numeric(), sep=",", quiet=TRUE)`
 Данные выглядят так:
     `[#User: "TEST", #myDate: "21.11.2017", #data: [87066, 87066, 87640, 86779, 87066, 87497, 87066, 87927, 87640]]`, в связи с чем видимо, возникает проблема:

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines,
>   na.strings,  :    scan() expected 'a real', got '[#User:"TEST"'

Я пробовала аргумент `skip`, но в результате создаваемый объект становится пустым. Как можно импортировать только то, что внутри вторых квадратных скобок?

Comment: Пока так res <- scan("file.txt", what=character(), sep=",", quiet=TRUE)       res <- as.numeric(res[-c((1:7), length(res))])

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов решения.

Имеем две строки в текстовом файле вида:

> [#User: "TEST", #myDate: "21.11.2017", #data: [87066, 87066, 87640, 86779, 87066, 87497, 87066, 87927, 87640]]
>   [#User: "TEST", #myDate: "22.11.2017", #data: [87077, 87088, 87699, 86779, 87055, 87022, 87033, 87978, 87600]]

```
fl <- "D:\\tmp\\data.txt"
# считываем данные
res <- scan(fl, what=character(), sep=" ", quiet=TRUE)
```

> результат:
>
> [1] "[#User:"     "TEST,"       "#myDate:"    "21.11.2017," "#data:"      "[87066,"     "87066,"      "87640,"
>   [9] "86779,"      "87066,"      "87497,"      "87066,"      "87927,"      "87640]]"     "[#User:"     "TEST,"
>   [17] "#myDate:"    "22.11.2017," "#data:"      "[87077,"     "87088,"      "87699,"      "86779,"      "87055,"
>   [25] "87022,"      "87033,"      "87978,"      "87600]]"

```
# заменяем [ ] скобки на ""
res1 <- gsub("[\\[\\]\\,]", "", res, perl = TRUE)
```

> результат:
>
> [1] "#User:"     "TEST"       "#myDate:"   "21.11.2017" "#data:"     "87066"      "87066"      "87640"
>   [9] "86779"      "87066"      "87497"      "87066"      "87927"      "87640"      "#User:"     "TEST"
>   [17] "#myDate:"   "22.11.2017" "#data:"     "87077"      "87088"      "87699"      "86779"      "87055"
>   [25] "87022"      "87033"      "87978"      "87600"

```
# заменяем все элементы, содержащие буквы и с "." (для даты) значение NA
res2 <- ifelse (!grepl("[a-zA-Z\\.]",res1), res1, NA)
```

> результат:
>
> [1] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      "87066" "87066" "87640" "86779" "87066" "87497" "87066" "87927" "87640"
>   [15] NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      "87077" "87088" "87699" "86779" "87055" "87022" "87033" "87978" "87600"

```
# исключаем значения NA и преобразуем в числа
res3 <- as.numeric(na.omit(res2))
```

> финальный результат:
>
> [1] 87066 87066 87640 86779 87066 87497 87066 87927 87640 87077 87088 87699 86779 87055 87022 87033 87978 87600

Comment: Спасибо за такой вариант!